# GroubBox in Flex 3 with heading

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, panel, groupbox

I need to have a group box in flex 3 - simple border with a heading at the top but the heading at the top should not have any border line through it.

I searched on the Net and the closest that I could get with source is

http://keg.cs.uvic.ca/flexdevtips/titledborder/srcview/

But the problem with this is that I can’t view in design mode what is on the group box. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Then I decided to go with canvases and an input box

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*">
<mx:TextInput 
        text="This should be my label" 
        x="124" y="72" 
        width="166" height="32" 
        borderStyle="solid" 
        fontWeight="bold" 
        color="#003366" backgroundColor="#D81010"/>

<mx:Canvas x="107" y="88" width="263" height="200" borderStyle="solid" label="Testst">
</mx:Canvas>            
</mx:Application>
```

But I can't seem to get the Textinput to be ontop of the canvas. There is a line through the box as in the below picture

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this or have a better idea?

thanks

Comment: In the attached URL in my question there are 2 files... a box and a window. The window acts like the group box and you can see what is inside at design time. thanks to the developer for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a custom component to work in design mode, you need to compile the code into a SWC library. Then reference the SWC library in your application project. I've never bothered to do this, I imagine you may get mixed results. I haven't bothered w/design mode in over 5 years :)

The reason the "window" component (in the URL that you linked to in the question) works in design mode is that it extends the Flex component `TitleWindow`. Since it extends an existing Flex component, I am assuming design mode knows how to render it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a component equivalent to "fieldset" in HTML.  It would be easier to use create component for better styling control.  For Flex 2/3, you may use [jwopitz-lib](http://code.google.com/p/jwopitz-lib/); but if you could use Flex 4 or above, try the [ShinyLib](http://blog.devinholloway.com/2012/03/flex-fieldset-component.html) component (specifically the [FieldSet class](https://www.assembla.com/code/shinylib/subversion/nodes/trunk/src/com/shinynet/shinylib/components/FieldSet.as) and [FieldSet skin](https://www.assembla.com/code/shinylib/subversion/nodes/trunk/src/com/shinynet/shinylib/skins/FieldSetSkin.mxml)).  It would be easier if you could migrate the application to Flex 4 or the latest Flex, you would be exposed to a lot more components.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We will however not upgrade flex unfortunately. Our company decided to stay with flex 3 until it is phased out. When that will be-no one knows. Think  we are stuck on flex 3 for the years to come.